# R - Convert Date Time as character into Seconds (numeric)

Tags: r, date

I am reading data time value from csv file stored as below

```
"2013-08-01 00:10:46"
"2013-08-01 00:10:51"
"2013-08-01 00:10:53"
"2013-08-01 00:11:04"
"2013-08-01 00:11:06"
```

While reading it is read as character and i want to convert it into seconds from 1970-01-01. I am able to achieve it using the below line of code but it takes ages to convert. Is there a better and faster way to achieve this

```
rstarttime  <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(rdata$starttime,origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Comment: You could try the [fasttime](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasttime/fasttime.pdf) package which is pretty fast :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lubridate`.

According to the following test, it can be around 12 times faster:

```
library(lubridate)
ttt <- c(
    "2013-08-01 00:10:46",
    "2013-08-01 00:10:51",
    "2013-08-01 00:10:53",
    "2013-08-01 00:11:04",
    "2013-08-01 00:11:06"
)

t <- Sys.time()
q <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(rep(ttt,50000),origin = "1970-01-01"))
t1 <- Sys.time() - t

t <- Sys.time()
q <- time_length(interval(ymd("1970-01-01"), rep(ttt, 50000)), "second")
t2 <- Sys.time() - t
```

The values I obtained for *t1* and *t2* are 6 seconds and 0.5 seconds respectively. So `lubridate` performs around 12 times faster.

Comment: Is time_length a function in lubridate package? I got an error running this code

Comment: Yep, page 56 of the manual in CRAN at [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf). What was the error?

Comment: I got this error - Error: could not find function "time_length". Strange

Comment: You might have a previous version of `lubridate`. Try to reinstall it: `install.packages("lubridate")` and rerun the code.